# Argument 1 passed in Laravel error. I don't know how to solve this error

Tags: php, laravel

I am currently using language detection and language translation API. However, this function, which works well on all controllers but requests ajax, has the same error as the title.

**ajax**

```
$("#translationBtn").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '{{route('translation')}}',
        type: 'post',
        data: {_token: "{{ csrf_token() }}",
                'material': $('#translationBox').val(),
            },
        success: function (data) {

            alert(data);

        }, error: function () {
            alert("error!!!!");
        }
    });
});
```

**Controller**
The value received through ajax was checked by the controller.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Home;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Controllers\Helper\Translation;

class TranslationController extends Controller
{
    use Translation;

    public function translation(Request $request){

       return $this->translation($request->material,$this>langCode($request->material));

    }
}
```

**Route**

```
Route::post('translation', 'Home\TranslationController@translation')- 
>name('translation');
```

**API**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Helper;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

trait Translation 
{

     public static function langCode($papago){

        $client_id      =  config('papago.client_sening_id');
        $client_secret  =  config('papago.client_sening_secret');
        $encQuery = urlencode($papago);
        $postvars = "query=".$encQuery;
        $url = "https://openapi.naver.com/v1/papago/detectLangs";
        $is_post = true;
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, $is_post);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postvars);
        $headers = array();
        $headers[] = "X-Naver-Client-Id: ".$client_id;
        $headers[] = "X-Naver-Client-Secret: ".$client_secret;
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        $response = curl_exec ($ch);
        $status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        //   echo "status_code:".$status_code."<br>";
        curl_close ($ch);
        if($status_code == 200) {
            // echo $response['langCode'];
            $json = json_decode($response, true);
            $langCode = $json['langCode']; 
        } else {
            echo "점검 중";
            // echo "Error 내용:".$response;
        }
        return $langCode;    
    }

    public static function translation($papago,$langCode) {

          $client_id      = config('papago.client_language_translation_id');
          $client_secret  = config('papago.client_language_translation_secret');
          $encText = urlencode($papago);


          if($langCode == "ko"){
            $postvars = "source=ko&target=ja&text=".$encText;

          }else if($langCode == "ja"){
            $postvars = "source=ja&target=ko&text=".$encText;

          }else{
            $postvars = "source=ko&target=ja&text=".$encText;
          }

          $url = "https://openapi.naver.com/v1/language/translate";
          $is_post = true;
          $ch = curl_init();
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, $is_post);
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
          curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postvars);
          $headers = array();
          $headers[] = "X-Naver-Client-Id: ".$client_id;
          $headers[] = "X-Naver-Client-Secret: ".$client_secret;
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
          $response = curl_exec ($ch);
          $status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
          //   echo "status_code:".$status_code."<br>";
          curl_close ($ch);

          if($status_code == 200) {  
            $json = json_decode($response, true);   //json_decode는  디코딩 된 json문자열을 연관배열로 만든다.
            $translation = $json['message']['result']['translatedText']; 

        } else {
            $translation = '점검 중';
            //   echo "Error 내용:".$response;
          }
          return  $translation;
    }
}
```

I'm making a mini-translator and it worked. But it's not working out. I can't figure out what's wrong with my way. Just

> Argument 1 passed to
>   App\Http\Controller\Home\TranslationController::translation() must be
>   an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, string Given, call in
>   C:xampp\Helmer\Helabor\Projectment 1 passed to
>   App\Http\Controller\Home\TranslationController::translation() must
>   be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, string Given, called
>   in\xperms\Project\triler.php:14)

I don't know this error.

Comment: What's the question? The error message seems to explain the issue, your translation method in the controller class requires the first arg to be of type `Illuminate\Http\Request`. The fix is to pass the expected object, no?

Comment: `return $this->translation($request->material,$this>langCode($request->material)); ` is wrong. `translation` is a static function,

Comment: You're probably getting confused by using traits, and having the same method name in both the controller and the trait the controller uses. Easier to use different names if they are independent.

Comment: as @Jonnix said, this could be caused by your Controller method name and trait method name being identical. Essentially you are calling the `TranslationController::translation()` in the same method.

I would used verbs rather than nouns in my method names as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using function name `translation` in 
`Class TranslationController` and `Trait Translation`. One is `static` and other is `instance`.
Calling `instance` method instead of `static`.
Better to use different name to avoid your confusion.

Your current code is doing recursion and not even going to trait method.

Rename trait method to something else and try.

Comment: You missed such a small thing! Thank you. I feel like I've grown up thanks to my friend!